# Unable to create traindata for tesseract (mac os x)

Tags: tesseract, leptonica

I'm trying to create train data for a specific font for tesseract and failing at the following command:

```
tesseract eng.uknumberplate.exp0.tiff foo bach.nochop makebox
```

and i get the following output in the terminal.

```
read_params_file: Can't open bach.nochop
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02.02 with Leptonica
Error in findTiffCompression: function not present
Error in pixReadStreamTiff: function not present
Error in pixReadStream: tiff: no pix returned
Error in pixRead: pix not read
Unsupported image type.
```

I have installed tesseract and leptonica through MacPort.

following is the output of tesseract -v command in terminal.

```
tesseract 3.02.02
 leptonica-1.68
  zlib 1.2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `batch.nochop`, not `bach.nochop`.

Comment: not related to the question but I recommend installing Tesseract via homebrew.

Comment: that has been a typing mistake and thanks for pointing out. removed tesseract, leptonica and macports as well and installed all of them through homebrew. still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the `colorspace` of your TIFF. Use [`ImageMagick`](http://www.imagemagick.org) to convert your pdf file into a TIFF image:

```
$convert -density 300 -depth 8 or 4 file.pdf output.tif 
$convert output.tif -colorspace rgb -type truecolor output.tif
```

And after this try to run `makebox` cmd.